# Python UDP server cannot accept client connection

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I want my server script to find a client which has connected to the server and then have the server send back a message to the client.

I sucessfully connected and can send bytes from client to server but I have had trouble sending from server to client. I have tried to use `clientSocket, address = mySocket.accept()` to find the client which has connected but then I get back the error message:

- OSError: [WinError 10045] The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced

**Server**

```
import socket

mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
myIP = socket.gethostname()
myPort = 1234

mySocket.bind((myIP, myPort))



while True:

    clientSocket, address = mySocket.accept()

    clientSocket.send(bytes("Connected", "utf-8"))
```

**Client**

```
import socket



myIP = socket.gethostname()
myPort = 1234
s1 = "string1"
s2 = "string2"
s3 = "string3"

mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
mySocket.sendto(bytes(s1, "utf-8"), (myIP, myPort))
mySocket.sendto(bytes(s2, "utf-8"), (myIP, myPort))
mySocket.sendto(bytes(s3, "utf-8"), (myIP, myPort))
```

I've seen tutorials to used `accept()` for this purpose but it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: You need to keep reading about UDP. There is no `accept()` step. The tutorials you read were either about TCP or rubbish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SOCK_DGRAM` creates a UDP, not TCP, socket. You can't use `send()` on a UDP socket because they are never in a "connected" state. Which also means you can't use `accept()` because UDP sockets are not connection oriented. You probably want a `SOCK_STREAM` type socket. If you really want a UDP (datagram) socket see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/udp-server-client-implementation-c/ for one tutorial on how they work.